# Store complex type in flutter sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

how to store complex type in sqflite for example :
the table person(id,name,email,List cars);
where the car is  an entity that have an id and a type ?
is there any solution like how to store it (like a Blob or in a new table and link it to the person table ) ?

Comment: just two tables (`people` and `cars`)? i dont think its a complex "type"

Answer (score 4):

You can´t in a simple table. I understand your point, you want to store, for example, something like this:

```
citizen = {
  "name":"",
  "id":"",
  "childrens":{
     children1:{
       "name":"",
       "id":"",
     }
     children2:{
       "name":"",
       "id":"",
     }
  }
}
```

This is because sqflite is a tool to use the device sqlite and this DB works under apache software. That means, Sqflite stores data as well sql DB stores data and you can't store objects in a sql table.

You should create other table for each complex data as you need. Something like this (as pseudocode):

```
'CREATE TABLE Citizen ('
          ' id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
          ' name TEXT,'
          ' children1Id INTEGER,'
          ' children2Id INTEGER,'
          '); '
'CREATE TABLE Children ('
          ' id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
          ' name TEXT'
          ')'
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really about mobile development and more about SQL DB and more generally speaking database management.

To answer directly you need create a table for car with an `car-id` and you need to know the relation between a person and a car to make the link:

- 1 - 1 : a person can only have one car and a car can only belong to one person
- 1 - n : a person can have multiple cars but a car can only belong to one person
- n - 1 : a person can only have one car but a car can have multiple owners
- n - n : finally the most complex case a person can only have car & a car can have multiple owners

In the three first case you set the id in the one (e.g 1-n : you put in the car table an field `owner-id` which is the id of the owner)

In the last case you need to create a matching table with : `matching-id` `car-id` `person-id`