# How to work with nested Models in Sqlflite Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, model

I am going to be working with [sqlflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) package in Flutter, and I have been reading a lot about it. However, everywhere I find the example being shown for the **single model**, that is

```
SingleModel{
  String data1, data2;

  ....
}
```

I have followed

- [Store list of objects in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55237612/5362583)
- [Sqlflite operation in Flutter](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2018/09/27/sqlite-database-operations-in-flutter/)

these as well, but that did not quite resolve it. My main requirements is to work with the data like this:

```
user: {
  'id': unique_key,
  'name': 'abc',
  'courses': [
    { 'coursename': 'some_coursename'},
    { 'coursename': 'some_other_coursename'}
  ]
}
```

I have designed my model correctly,

**UserModel Class**

```
class UserModel{
  int id;
  String name;
  List<Course> _courses;

  UserModel.set(Map data){
    this.id = data['id'];
    this.name = data['name'];
    if(data['courses'] != null)
         this.courses = [data['courses']];
  }

  // append more courses
  void setMorCourses(Map course){
     // checking for duplicate errors
     if(!this.courses.contains(course['course']))
         this.courses.add(course['course'])
  }
}
```

Now, I am confused on how to use the Nested Model with `sqlflite`. I believe I need to work in the `DatabaseHelper` class.

**Course Class**

```
class CourseModel{
  String coursename;

  CourseModel.set(Map data){
    this.coursename = data['coursename'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Any references @RaviPatel?

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353469/store-complex-type-in-flutter-sqflite

Comment: But @RaviPatel none of them gave me a reference of storing the item like `JSON`. It says to create two tables, that is vague.

Comment: This is a better way to do this so i prefer you to do store object with this

Comment: for JSON here is a reference link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62815607/how-to-store-a-complex-json-response-from-api-in-local-database-in-flutter